# Union half-edge edges

Tags: c#, geometry, mesh

I am having  some  issues when I want to union 2 naked half edges because I want to get a solid mesh. Sometimes after using external libraries I get naked edges on spots I do not want. Therefor I want to union the naked edges one by one so that it will be closed.

If you look at the picture below, I have the 2 red lines edge A and edge B. And I want to get the orange vertices and move them the the average center and union the 2 half edges.

[image]

What I tried, is that I get the vertice average. Remove 1 of the vertices, loop through all the Face.StartVertice to replace the old vertice index with the one 1 want to keep. Change the NextHalfedge on and edge and the PrevHalfedge, and also for the twin edge. But somehow I don't get the results I want. See my code below:

```
    public void UnionEdges(int edgeIndex1, int edgeIndex2)
    {
        Halfedge edge1 = Halfedges[edgeIndex1];
        Halfedge edge2 = Halfedges[edgeIndex2];

        edge2.StartVertex = edge1.StartVertex;

        Halfedge nextEdge1 = Halfedges[edge1.NextHalfedge];
        Halfedge prevEdge2 = Halfedges[edge2.PrevHalfedge];

        prevEdge2.NextHalfedge = edge1.NextHalfedge;
        nextEdge1.PrevHalfedge = edge2.PrevHalfedge;

        Halfedge prevEdge1 = Halfedges[edge1.PrevHalfedge];
        prevEdge1.NextHalfedge = edgeIndex2;

        Halfedge nextEdge2 = Halfedges[edge2.NextHalfedge];
        nextEdge2.PrevHalfedge = edgeIndex1;

        int edge1Twin = Halfedges.GetPairHalfedge(edgeIndex1);
        int edge2Twin = Halfedges.GetPairHalfedge(edgeIndex2);
        Halfedge twinEdge1 = Halfedges[edge1Twin];
        Halfedge twinEdge2 = Halfedges[edge2Twin];

        twinEdge1.StartVertex = twinEdge2.StartVertex; 
        twinEdge1.NextHalfedge = twinEdge2.NextHalfedge; 
        twinEdge1.PrevHalfedge = twinEdge2.PrevHalfedge;

        // Update the FirstHalfedge of the corresponding face of edge2
        for (var i = 0; i < Faces.Count; i++)
        {
            var face = Faces[i];    
            if(face.FirstHalfedge == edgeIndex2)
            {
                face.FirstHalfedge = edgeIndex1;
            }
        }

        // Mark the vertex and halfedges as deleted
        Vertices[edge2.StartVertex].OutgoingHalfedge = -1;

        Halfedges[edgeIndex2].StartVertex = -1;
        Halfedges[edgeIndex2].AdjacentFace = -1;
        Halfedges[edgeIndex2].NextHalfedge = -1;
        Halfedges[edgeIndex2].PrevHalfedge = -1;

        Halfedges[edge2Twin].StartVertex = -1;
        Halfedges[edge2Twin].AdjacentFace = -1;
        Halfedges[edge2Twin].NextHalfedge = -1;
        Halfedges[edge2Twin].PrevHalfedge = -1;
    }
```